# Firefox Search Shortcut not behaving as expected

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Chrome:
When I assign a shortcut to one of the Search Engines, for example "ex" for "example.com", I go to address bar, type "ex" and then press "TAB", it searches with example.com

Firefox:
When I assign a shortcut to one of the Search Engines, for example "ex" for "example.com", I go to address bar, type "ex" and then press "TAB", it goes a to suggestion or historical search keyword.

How can I get the same functionality in Firefox? I dont want my keyword to start with @.